# Which DICOM Server is the most reliable server for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have ConQuest DICOM server running on my Windows 7 machine. I am not happy with the speed and stability. Are there alternatives to that server I could try?

Greetings

Comment: There's a new Healthcare IT proposal (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) on Area 51 where this question would be a great fit, once the site is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[K-PACS](http://www.k-pacs.net/) is perhaps a freeware option.

A possible commercial product is [LEADTOOLS](http://www.leadtools.com/) by LEAD Technologies (costly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit biased, but the [ClearCanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca) [ImageServer](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/Creations/ImageServer/tabid/104/Default.aspx) is an open source DICOM server.  It supports the standard DICOM Storage and Query/Retrieve services, as you would expect in a DICOM server.  There's also an alpha version that has a Silverlight based web viewer included.

The ImageServer requires SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2 to function, and can work with the Express versions of those databases.  (2008 R2 Express is recommended due to the larger allowed database size.)

The ImageServer is being used in a large teaching hospital in Toronto as their primary PACS system.  Its also been widely downloaded and used in other settings.

On a final note, this question may find a better home on the [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) Stack Exchange site when it gets to beta.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [JVS DICOM Server](http://jvsmicroscope.uta.fi/?q=jvsdicom_server#download). I have been running it on server for couple of months now without crash. It simple, stable and open source.